# How do I cite Google Public Data in my bibliography (APA format)?

Tags: citations, apa

I'm writing a paper which uses an APA6-style bibliography. I'm referring to a graph from [Google Public Data](http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=l&met_y=it_net_user_p2#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=it_net_user_p2&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=region&idim=country%3aCHN%3aUSA&ifdim=region&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false).  What should my in-text citation say, and how should I cite it?

I'm not sure if I should use `(Google, 2010)` or `(Google Public Data, 2010)`.  Then, I actually need to cite two different graphs.  How will I differentiate between the two using my in-text citations?

Comment: [This "cut-down" APA6 guide](http://www.muhlenberg.edu/library/reshelp/apa_example.pdf) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the rule of thumb with web pages is to treat the title of the page or the domain as the title of the inline citation, so if the page title is 'Google Public Data', go with that. In practice I think that 'Google' is a little too general, because of the number of products Google provide. You would also need to provide the url in your full citation.

I found the following on the APA site that suggests you can just number the graphs in your inline citation

Because the material does not include page numbers, you can include any of the following in the text to cite the quotation (from pp. 170–171 of the Publication Manual):

> A paragraph number, if provided; alternatively, you could count paragraphs down from the beginning of the document.
>   An overarching heading plus a paragraph number within that section.
>   A short title in quotation marks, in cases in which the heading is too unwieldy to cite in full.

Because there is no date and no author, your text citation would include the title (or short title) "n.d." for no date, and paragraph number (e.g., "Heuristic," n.d., para. 1). The entry in the reference list might look something like this:

> Heuristic. (n.d.). In Merriam-Webster’s online dictionary (11th ed.). Retrieved from http://www.m-w.com/dictionary/heuristic

(adapted from the sixth edition of the APA Publication Manual, © 2010)

Comment: I'm so glad there are people around here with diverse sets of knowledge. I never would've been able to answer this.